# how to start android application from my application but the application should not be visible to others

Tags: android

supposing that i have created an application "MyApp" and it contains a button.When this button is clicked it should start another application say"App".this application "App" should not be available in any other part of the phone. 
                         please help me with this.
                              thank you.

Comment: with 'not be available' you mean it shouldn't show up in the settings / application or the package manager? I don't think it's possible. Or do you mean the permissions by other apps to start your 'App' other than 'MyApp'?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try doing a service instead of App.

Invoke your service when needed from your app. By this, only MyApp will be visible outside.